# AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'apply_tfms'

Tags: pytorch

I am getting this error when I am predicting image class using `learn.predict(img)`
the image file format is `png`

```
AttributeError: PngImageFile object has no attribute apply_tfms
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, runnable code example that shows the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Google PngImageFile => http://code.nabla.net/doc/PIL/api/PIL/PngImagePlugin/PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile.html

Google apply_tfms => https://docs.fast.ai/vision.image.html#Image.apply_tfms

The call is expecting a fastai [Image](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.image.html#Image) but it seems you're passing in a PIL Image.

It's impossible to tell for sure without actual code, but that seems a likely reason.